# Is there an efficient algorithm to project a vector onto the eigenbasis of a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis

Let $H$ be a symmetric matrix over $\mathbb R^n$. Given some vector $u$, I would like to express $u$ in the eigenbasis for $H$. Can this be done efficiently, perhaps using some kind of iterative method? I know there are iterative methods for computing the eigenbasis itself, but computing the entire eigenbasis would represent quadratically more data than I actually need ($n^2$ reals rather than only $n$), so I was hoping I might be able to get a speed up by using a more targeted method.

I only have implicit access to $H$ - i.e. I can compute matrix-vector products $Hx$. I would like to avoid having to actually compute $H$ if possible, although I would be happy with anything faster than computing $H$ and then diagonalizing it directly.

Comment: Of course, having access to matrix–vector products $H x$ gives access to the entries of $H$ *via* $H_{i j} = \langle e_i, H e_j\rangle$.  (It's needless to say in this audience, but I do wonder what limitation is expressed by requiring that you access $H$ only in this way.)

Comment: @LSpice Yes. I suppose "avoiding computing $H$" means something like computing only sub-linearly many matrix-vector products, which does seem like quite a big ask.

Comment: The eigenvalues are not given? Can there be multiple eigenvalues?

Comment: @MarkSapir $H$ is positive semi-definite, is the only information we have about the eigenvalues.

Comment: so is it symmetric of positive semidef?

Comment: @MarkSapir Sorry, I usually think of as PSD matrices as being symmetric by definition. It's both. I left out the PSD in the question because I felt it probably wasn't useful, but I'm happy to assume it if it makes the problem significantly easier.